# BuildConfig.groovy and grails-gradle-plugin

Tags: grails, gradle

We started with migrating our Grails application to Gradle using the grails-gradle-plugin (2.1.0).
As the documentation suggests the BuildConfig.groovy is ignored.

How do we specified grails configuration options?
E.g. grails.servlet.version

putting it in application.properties seems to be ignored as well

We are using:

- Grails 2.3.11
- Gradle: 1.9
- Grails-Gradle-Plugin: 2.1.0

Thank you in advance

Edward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not suggest that `BuildConfig.groovy` will be totally ignored but it indicates that it will no more be used to resolve dependencies (and grails plugins which are also a form of dependency).

> The consequence of this is that the BuildConfig.groovy is no longer
>   consulted for **repository or dependency information**. All repositories
>   and dependencies MUST be configured via Gradle.

[**Refer it again.**](http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/guide/usage.html#deps)

You can still use `BuildConfig.groovy` for other purposes (`grails.servlet.version` etc)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.
However, it still seems that the grails.servlet.version is ignored.
Getting the following exception when depoying on Tomcat 6:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext